# Как разбить диск на два раздела?

Tags: windows

Доброго времени суток! Посоветуйте, какую программу поставить на `Windows server 2000` для разбиения диска на два раздела. Стандартные программы по разбиению диска не работают.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Стандартные программы - это `fdisk`, например, сносит разделы, создает новые. Не стандартные программы, о которых Вы говорите, пытаются менять размер разделов, но не гарантируют сохранность данных. По этому лучший вариант - слить данные на отдельный носитель и разбивать разделы как душе угодно, в пользу потери производительности.

Comment: Мне сносить раздел не надо, а надо изменить размер раздела и создать новый раздел на месте свободного места. Кроме fdisk что-нибудь под винду посоветуйте.

Comment: Если Вы все внимательно прочитали, что я Вам написал выше то тогда пожалуйста http://www.goldsoftware.ru/easeus-partition-master

Comment: спасибо, за совет

Answer (score 0):

К своему стыду :-[ держу всегда при себе ZverDVD - там в загрузочных утильках есть Acronis Disk Director - никогда не подводил, разбивает, ресайзит. Без проблем. Загубленных разделов на его счету нет :)